# Rails 4, Heroku doesn't recognize precompiled manifest-(fingerprint).json

Tags: heroku, manifest, ruby-on-rails-4, precompiled

After upgrading to Rails 4, public/assets/manifest.yml is not generated anymore. Instead the different formatted manifest-(fingerprint).json is present.
But it seems to me that the server is still looking for the old manifest.yml format, ignoring the .json version?

I see other questions based on similar problems, but they seems to be sovled by upgrading to Rails 4, adding rails_12factor to gem file, setting serve_static_assets = true, etc., but none of these solutions seems to have any effect in my scenario.

I am tired and uninspired due to this annoying problem, any help will be appreciated!

Logfile from Heroku:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/layouts/test/test.html"):
```

Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
...
gem "compass-rails", github: "milgner/compass-rails", ref: "1749c06f15dc4b058427e7969810457213647fb8"
...
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

production.rb

```
RailsFoundationAngular::Application.configure do
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true  
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil
end
```

I am using Angular and their ui-router, and this is the part of my routes.js.coffee where the test.html is linked:

```
    .state "root",
      url: "/"
      views:
        "root":
          controller: "ApplicationController"
          templateUrl: "/assets/layouts/test/test.html"
```

I have also tried precompiling locally, but as I am using Rails 4 here as well, still no manifest.yml is created, only the .json version.
Of course, everything is working just perfectly in development...

**So my actual cuestion:**
How do I make Heroku recognize and use the manifest-(fingerprint).json -file, or alternative ways to make this work?

Comment: Now I actually found a usable workaround here: [no route matches for assets/images in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11128672/2597056).
Renamed the routes.js.coffee to routes.js.coffe.erb, and linked file as `templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('layouts/test/test.html') %>"`.
Now I'll just have to change every file reference in the souce like this. Actually, I thought this was exactly what the manifest file was expected to do for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, that Heroku already does recognize and use the manifest-(fingerprint).json -file. The "workaround" in my comment above, is the proper way to reference these files, and by doing so, the manifest-file is used the way it's ment to be used.

Renaming the file with the internal link to .erb, and referencing like this: `templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('layouts/test/test.html') %>"` does the trick. All internal files, images, and html -files should be referenced like this.

It's all described very thoroughly here: [Asset-pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

It seems so simple and straightforward now, but I really spent a lot of time trying to get the wrong way around this from the beginning.
I hope this answer can save the time for someone else.

Comment: Could you please clarify this answer? What did your asset paths look like before the fix? I'm having the same issue, my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555906/heroku-ignores-public-assets-manifest-json