# sometimes javascript run perfect and sometimes not in ruby on rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, sprockets, turbolinks

I  used datepicker in calendar it shows perfect but not shows the arrow button to change month. and also give error sometimes like this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png")
```

[image: Datepicker issue]

**datepicker.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
});
```

**css**
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ABPrime/SAVs2/)

sorry for too long question and tell me if i miss something.

Big thanks in advance

**Edit:**
I observed that when i delete the public/assets directory and then enter rake assets:precompile this time error is not showing but arrow still is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like turbolinks problem which are added to rails 4 by default. In turbolinks $(document).ready is not always firing. You can see more information about turbolinks and some suggestions how to use them here [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=asciicast) or you can add to some links

```
data: { no_turbolink: true }
```

You can also just remove the turbolinks from gemfile if you don't need them. Also check if you have the ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png in

```
/assets/images/
```

Comment: yup i guess turbolinks cause problem some where i read this. but bro my image exist in /assets/images/

Comment: and i also try rake assets:precompile

Comment: Can you add a css where this image is used?

Comment: Turbolinks are responsible for strangely working javascript. Icon problem is connected with wrong path to image in css or with some require in sprockets application.css

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: path is correct i check may be problem is sprockets .

Comment: I don't know how you reference to the image, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519997/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-assets-images-control-t and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095897/no-route-matches-for-assets-images-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow the instruction here. Basically you have to tell javascript to also execute on page:load.

Credit to [Meltemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63761/meltemi)

Coffee:

```
ready = ->

  ...your coffeescript goes here...

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Javascript:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Answer (score 1):

First, install `jquery-turbolinks` gem. And then, don't forget to move your included Javascript files from end of body of your `application.html.erb` to its `<head>`.

As [described here](https://coderwall.com/p/ypzfdw/faster-page-loads-with-turbolinks), if you have put the application javascript link in the footer for speed optimization reasons, you will need to move it into the  tag so that it loads before the content in the  tag. This solution worked for me.