# Rails - jQuery is some times not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an Rails application where in the `application.js` is specified following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require gmaps/gmaps
//= require underscore
//= require_tree .
```

jQuery is loaded by the Rails system.

The problem is that some times it looks like jQuery is not loaded, because - for example - Google maps - are not working (and other jQuery-related stuff). After refresh/reload is everything working, but this behavior is very unpleasant.

As I have never met with this issue, I am not sure what could be wrong - I'll try to load jQuery from Google (through an HTML link in the header of the page), will see it if help.

However, haven't any of you guys faced this issue and have a tip to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate still you get help from this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254379/sometimes-javascript-run-perfect-and-sometimes-not-in-ruby-on-rails-4]

Answer (score 1):

**Turbolinks**

The best tip I could give would be that it's a `turbolinks` issue:

> After refresh/reload is everything working, but this behavior is very
>   unpleasant.

What you've described is a typical hallmark of Turbolinks issues - basically when you use Turbolinks, it only reloads the `<body>` tag of your page through Ajax. This leaves the `<head>` tag intact, which makes Javascript think your page elements have not changed (thus preventing them from binding)

--

**Fixes**

The ways around this are either to use:

[**delegation**](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Because javascript can only bind events to elements present in the DOM, it will not be able to process any elements which appear *after* the DOM is loaded. To get around this, you can *delegate* your event bindings from a container which is there all the time, typically `document`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#your_element", function() {
   // do stuff here
});
```

--

[**Turbolinks events**](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events)

Another method to get around this is to encapsulate your events inside functions, which can be called using `Turbolinks events`:

```
var tester = function(){
    //do stuff here
};

$(document).on("page:load ready", tester);
```

--

[**JQuery turbolinks gem**](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks):

```
#Gemfile
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require gmaps/gmaps
//= require underscore
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Thank you, Rich, for your message. I checked it deeper and when I am in the application and click on the logo (means it redirects me to the root of the application), then the jQuery events don't work. But when I make a refresh, it's working, so it's slightly different behavior than in the OP.

However, I've tried to install the **jquery-turbolinks** gem, but it didn't help to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have any console errors or anything? I'm pretty sure it's a Turbolinks issue